# Disabling onTap when using pinch to zoom

Tags: android

I have a map view which has overlay items on top of them. The overlay items have an action when they are taped on.
The problem is when I use pinch to zoom if it my fingers happen to be at a location of an item when I lift them  the onTap() is called. how could i prevent this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

implement the motioneventListener instead of your current eventListener for your overlayItem and check the pointer count

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getPointerCount() == 1)
    { 
     // do onTap stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this is great for android 2.0 and above, how about for 1.6?

Comment: 1.6 doesn't have multitouch unless they are using a modded kernel. I would say its safe to assume anyone using a mod isn't running 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I got to in the end If it is any help to anyone:

```
    private static Method           GetPointCountMethod;
    private boolean                 mIsTouchMove    = false;

    private static boolean mTapable = true;

    static {
        // Check if the getPointerCount method is availabe (aka api level 5)
        try {
            GetPointCountMethod = MotionEvent.class.getMethod("getPointerCount");
            /* success, this is a newer device */
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            /* failure, must be older device */
        }
    };

// Invoke the getPointCount Method if it exists
    private int getPointCount(MotionEvent event)
    {
        try {
            return (Integer) GetPointCountMethod.invoke(event);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        // Set the tappable to be only when the map is realy just tapped and not moved or zoomed
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (GetPointCountMethod != null) {
                if (getPointCount(event) == 1) {

                    if (mIsTouchMove) {
                        mIsTouchMove = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        mTapable  = true;
                        // Finaly - a Tap! : 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            mTapable  = (false);
            mIsTouchMove = true;
        }
        // let the rest do their job
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

There is still no support for 1.6 and that is why this is still open ill wait to see if there is a way to do it also in 1.6

Comment: You can't do multi-touch in Android below 2.0. There are no methods in MotionEvent to support it. Your solution to check for the existence of that method is sound, in order to figure out if you can do multi-touch or not.

Comment: Oh, OK thanks... Never actually thought about that I will not have this problem in 1.6. thanks